# Cherry Gentix BT mouse: control extra buttons?

Tags: macos, mouse, ventura

The [Gentix BT](https://www.cherryamericas.com/gentix-bt?___store=cherry_us_en) mouse by Cherry has two extra buttons on the left hand side. Those are "hard wired" to browser next/back. Cherry offers software to assign different functions to the buttons, but only for Windows.

Is there a way to assign other functionality to these buttons on MacOs?